# How do i loop through the twitter api results using cURL for a given username

Tags: php, curl, twitter, simplexml

Im trying to loop through the twitter timeline of a given user through the results of `SimpleXMLElement` Object. For some reason the code below only shows one result.

1. What am i doing wrong here?
2. How do i search for a string of text within the "description" tag of the xml/rest result. Ex. Im trying to find all tweets that contain the string "I love coding".

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?  screen_name=twitterusername",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach($xml as $x){
echo '<h2>' . $x->title . '</h2>';
echo '<a href="'.$x->link .'">Link</a>';
echo '<br><em>' .$x->description .'<em>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @ilanco. I think its pretty obvious Im rather new to this site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two errors here.

Firstly, you are requesting RSS, you need to request the XML

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=edent
```

Secondly you want to load the XML as a string, like this

```
$tweets = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Then go through them like this

```
foreach ($tweets as $status) {
    echo $status->text;
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with SimpleXMLElement, but are you certain it's returning an array value to $xml? As far as I can see reading documentation to appears to only return a single element.

Comment: On this blog this person is looping through the results from SimpleXML. The diffence is that he is using a "for" loop than a "foreach" loop. Refer to: http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work with foreach if it returned the array as you expect. What kind of result do you get if you print_r($xml)? And what kind of result is in $response? Looking at those values will probably lead us closer to the answer.